# why perf record --count option doesn't work properly?

Tags: c, operating-system, perf

I've the following program

```
int main(){
    
    int a = 0;
    a += 1;

    return 0;
}
```

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

I want to count instructions by using perf tool
when i set -c  `--count` with 2 I understand that perf collects a sample for every 2 instructions.

When i execute the following

```
 gcc -O0 simple_main.cc
 sudo su
 perf stat ./a.out 

 Performance counter stats for './a.out':

              0,46 msec task-clock                #    0,488 CPUs utilized          
                 0      context-switches          #    0,000 /sec                   
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 /sec                   
                50      page-faults               #  108,640 K/sec                  
           722.745      cycles                    #    1,570 GHz                    
           696.848      instructions              #    0,96  insn per cycle         
           135.823      branches                  #  295,117 M/sec                  
             4.688      branch-misses             #    3,45% of all branches        
         3.613.725      slots                     #    7,852 G/sec                  
           779.430      topdown-retiring          #     21,6% retiring              
           439.315      topdown-bad-spec          #     12,2% bad speculation       
         1.417.147      topdown-fe-bound          #     39,2% frontend bound        
           977.831      topdown-be-bound          #     27,1% backend bound         

       0,000942582 seconds time elapsed

       0,001022000 seconds user
       0,000000000 seconds sys
```

It says I've 696k instructions total (my program + kernel instructions)

```
perf record -e instructions -c 2 ./a.out
```

```
perf report --stdio
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 1  of event 'instructions'
# Event count (approx.): 2
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol            
# ........  .......  .................  ..................
#
   100.00%  perf-ex  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] x86_pmu_enable


#
# (Cannot load tips.txt file, please install perf!)
#
```

I get 2 or sometimes nothing
but when i say `--count=12000`

```
root@rt7-laptop-vivo:/home/rt7/Desktop/omp_perf_example# perf record -e instructions -c 12000 ./a.out
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0,026 MB perf.data (52 samples) ]
root@rt7-laptop-vivo:/home/rt7/Desktop/omp_perf_example# perf report --stdio
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 52  of event 'instructions'
# Event count (approx.): 624000
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object         Symbol                                 
# ........  .......  ....................  .......................................
#
     7.69%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] __handle_mm_fault
     5.77%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] filemap_map_pages
     5.77%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] page_add_file_rmap
     5.77%  a.out    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  [.] add_to_global_resize
     3.85%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] next_uptodate_page
     3.85%  a.out    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  [.] _dl_profile_fixup
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] __cgroup_throttle_swaprate
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] __kmalloc
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] clear_page_erms
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] crng_make_state
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] do_mmap
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] do_open
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] find_vma
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] free_pipe_info
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] free_swap_cache
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] handle_mm_fault
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] ksys_mmap_pgoff
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] lock_page_memcg
     1.92%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]     [k] memcg_slab_post_alloc_hook
:
```

I get similar results to perf stat. It counted 624k instructions. why and how?

doesn't perf record -c N ./a.out mean collect a single sample after every N operations? in this case it should collect single sample after each 12000 instructions. Am i mistaken??

Comment: There are lower limits on sample periods you can set, especially as non-root, to stop user-space from flooding the CPU with interrupts.  Perhaps `-c 2` gets ignored because it's below that?  I tried to find what the limit is, but my google search didn't find it.